# Error while updating a record in APEX screen

Tags: oracle-apex

while updating a record using MRU its failing with below error.

1 error has occurred
Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process. current row version identifier = "C5F3645B026AA5646C00DC7B631C4D19" application row version identifier = "6A9323B62F641015FA4601421DFB03DE" (Row 1)

This is strange because I do not see any change in the data at backend.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.
AJ

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please mention your apex version. You're using a tabular form, how is it set up? Anything special about it? Could you possibly reproduce the behaviour on apex.oracle.com (workspaces are free and shareable, a great community resource)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a tabular form, check your query, then check the item. The item must match with the correct column in a database that is updatable.

Make sure that your column aliases match your column names (for updateable columns).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, the problem in my case that detail table has composite primary key,
so in application > column > Primary KeyPrimary Key
 property must all primary key field enable , not only one field.